# C# AutoMapper Map Flatten Object to List of Complex Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, automapper

Automapper I am trying to map simple object "Source" to a complex object "Dest"

Here I want to map field F2, F3, F4 to complex object `List <DestChild1>`

example

Source Obj:

```
 public class Source 
    {
       public int F1;
       public int F2;
       public int F3;
       public int F4;
    }

    Complex Object structure:

    public class Dest
    {
          public int F1;
          public List<DestChild1>  DestChild1;
     }

    public class DestChild1  
    {
       public int F2;
       public int F3;
       public DestChild2  DestChild2;
    }

    public class DestChild2  
    {
       public int F4;
    }


I was able to manually map it

Dest result = new Dest(){
F1 = source.F1,
DestChild1 =  new List<DestChild1>() {
 new DestChild1(){
   F2 = source.F2,
   F3 = source.F3,
   DestChild2 = new DestChild2() { F4 = source.F4 }
  }
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Please post real code. `Public` vs `public` indicates that this isn't real, and people can't paste this into VS to help provide an answer. It also looks like there might be classes unrelated to the question. In your text, please connect the dots clearly by referring to the classes by name. Otherwise people have to read the words and then try to figure out which classes you're referring to.

Comment: @scott I have edited as per your comment, btw it is just a sample to explain the problem. In real my object is so complex and I can't put everything here.

Comment: It's okay that you're not posting actual production code. But what you do post should still be something that we can work with. Honestly, my intent is to help, not nitpick. The text of your question still doesn't refer to class names. When you say "simple object", "complex object", and "complex list," we have to read the code to figure out which class is which. Instead you can just refer to the classes by their names. Also, descriptive text should be separate from code. (Finally, my suggestion would have been to map manually anyway. It's less work for the next person to understand.)

Comment: ya I have added my manual mapping sample

Comment: One problem you are going to run into is with the list you have in your above example. Even supposing that your classes looked like follows: class Source { int F1; int F2; int F3; int F4; int F5; int F6; int F7;} and you want F3-6 to be part of your list, how would you be able to know that F2-F4 need to be grouped together as one object in that list and F5-F7 as another object. How are you coming by this flat object to begin with? It might be easier to deal with making it complex farther up the chain

Answer (score 0):

Provided is a basic example of using reflection to accomplish what you are looking for. As I mentioned in my comment above, though, once you start adding collections it will become more complicated unless you have a way of knowing what should be grouped together in a sub object.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ObjectMapper
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Source source = new Source();
            source.F1 = 1;
            source.F2 = 2;
            source.F3 = 3;
            source.F4 = 4;

            Dest result = new Dest()
            {
                F1 = source.F1,
                DestChild1 = 
                     new DestChild1()
                     {
                         F2 = source.F2,
                         F3 = source.F3,
                         DestChild2 = new DestChild2() { F4 = source.F4 }
                     }
            };


            Dest dest2 = new Dest();
            SetValues(ref source, ref dest2);

            Console.WriteLine("Set breakpoint here so you can inspect object");
        }

        public static void SetValues<T1,T2>(ref T1 sourceObject, ref T2 destObject)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] pi = sourceObject.GetType().GetProperties();
            //Loop through each sourceObject Property
            foreach (PropertyInfo sourcePI in sourceObject.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                //Loop through each destination property to find matching destination property
                foreach (PropertyInfo destPI in destObject.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    //Within each destination property, look for attribute decorator that says this is the object we want to pair
                    foreach (SourceAttribute sourcePropertyToMatch in destPI.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SourceAttribute), true).Cast<SourceAttribute>())
                    {
                        //If the source object property we are on matches the attribute decorator of the destination object property, set its value
                        if (String.Compare(sourcePI.Name, sourcePropertyToMatch.Name, true) == 0 || String.Compare(sourcePI.Name, destPI.Name, true)==0)
                        {
                            //Get value from our source object that so we can set it to our destination value
                            object val = sourcePI.GetValue(sourceObject);

                            //Avoid null reference exception should we somehow be attempting to assign a null value to a non-nullable type
                            if (val != null)
                            {
                                destPI.SetValue(destObject, val, null);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    //if we get here, there was no source attribute matched. check if it is one of our subobjects and dive into it
                    var destObjectSubObject = destPI.GetValue(destObject);
                    if (destObjectSubObject is DestinationBaseObject)
                    {
                        MethodInfo setValMethodDef = typeof(Program).GetMethod("SetValues");
                        MethodInfo setValMethod = setValMethodDef.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { sourceObject.GetType(), destObjectSubObject.GetType() });
                        var parameters = new object[] { sourceObject, destObjectSubObject };
                        setValMethod.Invoke(null, parameters);

                        destPI.SetValue(destObject, destObjectSubObject);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Source
    {
        public int F1 { get; set; }
        public int F2 { get; set; }
        public int F3 { get; set; }
        public int F4 { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class DestinationBaseObject { }
    public class Dest: DestinationBaseObject
    {
        public Dest()
        {
            DestChild1 = new DestChild1();
        }
        [SourceAttribute("F1")]
        public int F1 { get; set; }
        public DestChild1 DestChild1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class DestChild1 : DestinationBaseObject
    {
        public DestChild1()
        {
            DestChild2 = new DestChild2();
        }
        [SourceAttribute("F2")]
        public int F2 { get; set; }
        [SourceAttribute("F3")]
        public int F3 { get; set; }
        public DestChild2 DestChild2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class DestChild2 : DestinationBaseObject
    {
        [SourceAttribute("F4")]
        public int F4 { get; set; }
    }
    public class SourceAttribute : Attribute
    {

        public SourceAttribute(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
        public String Name { get; private set; }
    }
}
```